# Formatting USB drive is disabled in gnome-disks

Tags: gnome-disk-utility, disk-formatting

I got a new USB stick I could not use. `gnome-disks` app shows that it's not formatted, but does not allow me to format it even when running it with superuser.

What could be the problem here, and how could I fix it? Are there other ways to format it?

[image: Disks app with Format Disk... menu disabled]

**P.S.**

After searching more, I runned `killall nautilus`, and after getting comment to this question I runned

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep usb
[16529.465186] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[16529.618724] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0a2b, bcdDevice= 0.10
[16529.618740] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[39243.153799] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
[39243.153800] usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
[39243.401751] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[39243.553002] usb 1-8: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[112326.656886] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[112326.805589] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=ffff, idProduct=1201, bcdDevice= 0.00
[112326.805606] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[112326.807682] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[112326.808138] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[112595.189378] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 5
[112607.286765] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[112607.435258] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=ffff, idProduct=1201, bcdDevice= 0.00
[112607.435272] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[112607.437263] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[112607.437931] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[112727.271087] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[112740.669742] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[112740.821498] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=ffff, idProduct=1201, bcdDevice= 0.00
[112740.821505] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[112740.822592] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[112740.822757] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[113046.811633] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 7
[113063.007045] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[113063.155281] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=ffff, idProduct=1201, bcdDevice= 0.00
[113063.155295] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[113063.157260] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[113063.157906] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
```

This output was long so I wanted to check if it was because I was trying different USB ports, so pulled out and inserted it in again, and got

```
[116444.162901] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 8
[116447.126321] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[116447.277233] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=ffff, idProduct=5678, bcdDevice= 2.00
[116447.277250] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[116447.277257] usb 1-1: Product: Disk 2.0
[116447.277263] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: USB
[116447.277269] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 4775771091744401963
[116447.280486] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[116447.281416] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
```

And it mounted as 2GB FAT16 drive, and Format Disk... is enabled.

Looks like the fix was to `killall nautilus` and reinsert the stick, but I'm not sure now.

Comment: Did you run the Disks application with normal privileges? GUI applications aren't supposed to be run as the root user and many applications will prevent you from performing certain actions if you try to run them as root.

Comment: I tried both, same result.

Comment: please edit your question including the output of `dmesg | grep usb`.

Comment: @Sad3ng I did that, and something else (I don't know what exactly) and that USB mounted as formatted.